What is the meaning of WDC for tournament status?
In the recent LPGA tournament results, Mizuho Americans Open, several players were shown with the status WDC while two were shown as WD. Clearly, WDC is a withdrawal but I could find nothing distinguishing a WDC from a WD.
As reported, the seven players with WDC withdrew due to viral infections.
Tournament Status (DQ, WD, NS, NC, DNF) makes no mention of the status.
What is the meaning of WDC for tournament status?

The difference between the WDs and WDCs are that the WDs have incomplete scorecards suggesting they withdrew during the course of the round while the WDCs have complete scorecards suggesting they withdrew after the completion of the round.
I wasn't able to confirm this, but I wonder if "WDC" stands for "withdrawing after completing round" or something similar.
WDC scorecard:

WD scorecards:



The WDC status is used on both the LPGA and EPSON tours. It has been in use since at least 2016 and in every case for which I could find information, the withdrawal was for "illness" but not "injury". See, the scorecard for Lilia Vu for a WDC after 13 holes in the fourth round. On X, "Lilia Vu has withdrawn from the HSBC Women’s World Championship during the fourth round due to illness."
